# Can't locate control from string

Tags: c#, click, controls

I have a custom extension method that (is supposed to) find a control via a string, and perform a click to that control. I've set up a break point and it nevers into the `if (c is ToolStripMenuItem)` Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? This is on WinForms.

```
   private void PerformClickfromString()
    {
        string item = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\controltest.txt");

        foreach (var c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ToolStripMenuItem)
            {
                var x = (ToolStripMenuItem)c;

                if (x.Name == item)
                {
                    x.PerformClick();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformClickfromString();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would print out all x.Names before the inner check and see which controls are beeing reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all nested items you need a recursive search. Here is an example; it collects all items in a `List<ToolStripMenuItem>` and the checks for the searched name. I have added that string to the signature of your call..:

```
private void PerformClickfromString(string s)
{
    foreach (var c in this.Controls)
    {
        List<ToolStripMenuItem> items = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();

        if (c is MenuStrip)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsItem in ((MenuStrip)c).Items)
            {
                GetAllMenuItems(items, tsItem);
            }
        }
        ToolStripMenuItem found = items.Find(x => x.Name == s);
        if (found != null) found.PerformClick();
    }
}


void GetAllMenuItems(List<ToolStripMenuItem> items, ToolStripMenuItem menu)
{
    items.Add(menu);
    foreach(ToolStripMenuItem m in menu.DropDownItems)
        GetAllMenuItems(items, m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToolStripMenuItem` is not considered a control, you must instead use its container

```
if(c is MenuStrip)
{
    foreach(ToolStripMenuItem tsItem in ((MenuStrip)c).Items)
    {
        if (tsItem.Name == item)
        {
            tsItem.PerformClick();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error when trying this: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type...does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip' because 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: Sorry, I just realised my mistake, try now

Comment: No errors, but no output either. is there a way to search ALL ToolStripItemMenu objects? example: File > Layer 1 > Layer 2. I need to get to Layer 2. It's only searching the 'File' topstrips

Comment: You can say `if(tsItem.Items != null)` I am pretty sure, that will check for sublevels

Comment: Maybe this calls for a recursive search..?

Comment: @TaW I don't feel as if that is necessary, the `if` in my last comment would be enough for this instance, though if there were three layers then a recursive search would certainly be better

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre No 'items' for tsItem that I can use; can't use `tsItem.Items`